# leaflet.js - spaces between tiles, blurred map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I use the map display using a class, in html I initialize the map. the size of the parent div is set to max using css. When first viewed, the map is displayed with gaps between the tiles and sharp, after any movement or zoom, the map is out of focus outside the gaps.
If I use F12 dev tools in chrome the gaps between the tiles disappear and the map is ultra sharp!
Please help. Chrome latest version, current leflet 1.9.4, monitor resolution 2560x1440.
Note: I went through and tried (perhaps) all the recommendations and proposed solutions on the net (the strange thing is that I have a problem with blurring and gaps, on the net these cases are solved separately. In particular, the problem with gaps between tiles should have been solved by version 1.9.4 leaflet ...)

**blurred, tiles**
[image]

**after pressing F12 (dev tools)**
[image]

class with map:

```
class Map {
constructor(containerId, initialCoordinates, zoomLevel) {
    this.containerId = containerId;
    this.initialCoordinates = initialCoordinates;
    this.zoomLevel = zoomLevel;
    this.map = null;
    this.parcels = null;
    this.points = null;
    this.actualPoint = { x: 0, y: 0 }
    this.mapBounds = {
                        min: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
                        max: { lat: 0, lng: 0 }
                     };
}

initializeMap () {
    proj4.defs("EPSG:5514", "+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.8333333333333 +alpha=30.288139722222 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=570.8,85.7,462.8,4.998,1.587,5.261,3.56 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs");
    //this.map = L.map(this.containerId).setView(this.initialCoordinates, this.zoomLevel);

    const osmap = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>', 
        keepBuffer: 0,
        detectRetina: true
    });
    //osmap.addTo(this.map);

    const googlemap = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        maxZoom: 20,
        subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2'],
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.google.com/maps">GoogleMap</a> contributors',
        keepBuffer: 0,  

    });

    const orto = L.tileLayer.wms("https://geoportal.cuzk.cz/WMS_ORTOFOTO_PUB/WMService.aspx?", {
        format: "image/png",
        layers: "GR_ORTFOTORGB",
        transparent: "false",
        minZoom: 5,
        maxZoom: 20,
        attribution: "©CUZK",
    });


    const layer_cuzk = L.tileLayer.wms("https://services.cuzk.cz/wms/wms.asp", {
        format: "image/png",
        layers: "KN",
        version: "1.3.0",
        transparent: "true",
        minZoom: 19,
        maxZoom: 22,
        attribution: "©CUZK",
        tileSize: 256,
        detectRetina: true
    });                

    this.map = L.map(this.containerId, {
        center: this.initialCoordinates,
        zoom: this.zoomLevel,
        layers: [osmap, layer_cuzk] // náhrada za AddTo
    });

    this.parcels = L.featureGroup();
    this.parcels.addTo(this.map);
    this.points = L.featureGroup();
    this.points.addTo(this.map);

    const baseLayers = {
        'osmap': osmap
        //'orto' : orto,
        //'google' : googlemap
    };

    const overlays = {
        //'cuzk': layer_cuzk,
    };

    const layerControl = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(this.map);

    /* reakce na práci s myší */
    this.map.on('click', (e) => {
        this.onMapClick(e);
    });

    this.map.on('moveend', (e) => {
        this.onMapMoveEnd(e);
    });
    
    this.map.on('zoomend', (e) => {
        this.onMapZoomEnd(e);
    });
    
}; /* inicializace END */
```

initialization in html

```
<div id="map" class="container-fluid hw-maxheight"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    const mymap = new Map('map', [49.68, 18.35], 18);
    mymap.initializeMap();
});
```

css

```
    .hw-maxheight {
height: 100%;
```

}